# How to fix zero accuracy in Deep Learning while the loss is fine

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have a dataset of 50x22 which includes 22 features. The target is to classify the target which is scaled from 1 to 5, equivalently 5 classes. I used random forest with 98% accuracy but the validation is 63% which is not satisfiable. That's why I decided to create a deep model and I created a model with 3 layers. The result of loss is satisfiable around 6.7*10e-4 but the accuracy is fixed with zero. I think there is some thing wrong in my code. So, what's the problem?

```
def build_and_compile_model(norm):
    model = keras.Sequential([
    norm,
    layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')
    ])
 model.compile(optimizer='sgd',
          loss='binary_crossentropy',
          metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy()])
return model

def plot_acc(history):
    plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'], label='accuracy')
    plt.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'], label='val_accuracy')
    plt.ylim([0, 1])
    plt.xlabel('Epoch')
    plt.ylabel('Accuracy [GSR]')
    plt.legend()
    plt.grid(True)

dnn_qoe_model = build_and_compile_model(feature_normalizer)
dnn_qoe_model.summary()

history = dnn_qoe_model.fit(
          train_features[:22], train_labels,
          validation_split=0.2,
          verbose=0, epochs=100)
plot_acc(history)
```

[the loss plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e72WJ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `loss='binary_crossentropy'` and `layers.Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')`, which are used for binary classification problems.

Since you are looking to predict one of 5 classes, you are looking at a multi class problem.

If your target is one hot encoded which would look like so: `[0,1,0,0,0]` for one class, you should use `layers.Dense(5,activation='softmax')` and `loss='categorical_crossentropy'`.

If your target isn't one hot encoded, which means the response is an integer referring to the class number, which would be `[1]` (position of the positive class) in the previous example, you should use `layers.Dense(5,activation='softmax')`, and change the loss function to `loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy'`, as your target variable is encoded as a sparse vector (refers to the index of the item containing a 1 in a vector of zeros)

Comment: It should be `activation = 'softmax'`, assuming labels are one-hot-encoded for loss function.

Comment: @Frightera Actually I changed but still the accuracy is zero.

Comment: @VincFort
 I changed the last layer to `layers.Dense(5, activation='softmax')` but I got `ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 5) are incompatible`. Sorry I am new to tensorflow.I should say that the target is just one column with numbers from 1 to 5 which I am in doubt if I use Dense(1) or Dense (5).

Comment: Edited my answer to explain

Comment: @VincFort thanks for your explanation. I changed my code to your structure but now, the accuracy is stocked at 50%. what is my problem?

Comment: 50% Accuracy when you have 5 classes is better than random, so your code seems to be working. There are many ways to increase accuracy, like adding more layers, training for longer, adding features, etc.

Comment: `layers.Dense(1,activation='softmax')` is wrong, the model is just outputting a vector of 1s (ones) everytime. It should be `layers.Dense(5,activation='softmax')` and loss function depends on your labels, if one-hot-encoded then it should be `categorical_crossentropy` otherwise your labels are integers; then `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`.

Comment: @VincFort I am wondered since the accuracy at the first epoch is 50% and it is going to be constant to end. By the way, should I do a try and error to find the best accuracy?

Comment: @Frightera I correct it in my new code. tnx